Referencing Prometheus recording rule value in description
spec:
  groups:
    - name: daily-user-reports
      rules:
        - record: percentage_matched_users_success
          expr: expression
        - record: percentage_matched_users_fail
          expr: expression
        - alert: DailyUserReport
          expr: vector(1)  
          for: 1d
          labels:
            severity: info
            environment: production
            owner: ops
            slack_channel: channel
            customer: user-reports
            emoji: ":eyes:"
          annotations:
             description: |
              **Daily User  Report**

              **Subject**
              - Success Rate: {{ $value "percentage_matched_users_success" | printf "%.2f" }}%
              - Failure Rate: {{ $value "percentage_matched_users_fail" | printf "%.2f" }}%

This is my Prometheus alert, I have recording rules and I want to reference their values in my description, prior to this I tried using query function, but it returns a data structure, the $value also is not working, as I'm getting errors. What is the correct way to reference the expression value?
